# Angular - My page is not displayed, path problem?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

My project is presented like this

`app` > `home` > `mark` > `opel`

[image]

When, the user clicks on the Opel hyperlink, this page does not run...

[image]

In home.component.html page, I have this:
We agree that the path is correct?

```
<ul>
  <li><a routerLink="mark/opel">Opel</a></li>
</ul>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I don't understand why the content of the Opel page is missing?

opel.component.html

```
<h1>Opel page</h1>
```

My code is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3ca9hc?file=src/app/home/home.component.html)

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: you are trying to access mark/opel however in your routing module you don't have that defined, if you wish to setup internal routing there is a different way to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to have good structure of your code (directories, naming, etc.) for maintenance and further development but the structure does not necessarily represent the routing structure.

The important things for the routing are the defined routes and you are missing the route to the `OpelComponent`.

To make your app work you need to add a route for `opel` in your `MarkRoutingModule`.

After adding the route your `MarkRoutingModule` would look like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MarkComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'opel', // <- This route here was missing
    component: OpelComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class MarkRoutingModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the current structure of the app you would have to explicitly map the path `opel` to the `OpelComponent`.

Take a look on the [adjusted code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mvwusc?file=src/index.html)